# Salesforce Marketing Cloud (ExactTarget) FULL OUTER JOIN

Tags: sql, salesforce, outer-join, exacttarget

I'm trying to use FULL OUTER JOIN in my Marketing Cloud query but it doesn't returns any results. If I use just regular JOIN I can merge some data but it's not what I need. Need to use FULL OUTER JOIN to get all data from table A and if it's possible some extra data to it from table B. I'm using code bellow:

```
SELECT B.Email, A.abandon_reason, A.basket_url, A.promo_code, A.product_ids, A.datetime, B.FirstName, B.LastName, B.Marketing, A.qtys
FROM A
FULL OUTER JOIN B
ON A.ContactKey = B.Email
WHERE A.EmailSend = 'False'
```

Thank you for any help and suggestions.

Comment: Hmm this looks ok, you dont get any syntax errors right?

Comment: Do you want everyone that dosnt exit in both tables, or do you want everyone, even if they exits in both? http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins/Visual_SQL_JOINS_orig.jpg

Comment: As Rasmus asked, do you get any syntax errors? Also, for SFMC questions, you will likely get a better response posting them at http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud

Comment: Hi guys, yes I don't have any syntax errors. @Gortonington thank you for the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your responses. At the end I solved this problem with filtered DE.